# Laragon local server with WordPress doesn't send email notifications via MailChimp for new blogposts

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

I use Laragon with WordPress to develop locally and then move my websites to Bluehost. I wanted to have a Subscribe button on a blog page so people can get notified of new blog posts. I signed up for MailChimp and used free version which generated for me HTML form embed. I placed that HTML in my index.php which handles blog posts.

Question: I am able to subscribe with new email addresses and see those in the Audience Contacts list in MailChimp dashboard but when I created a test post I don't get any notification emails about new content. Does it have to do with Laragon as this is local environment or some WordPress settings or it just on MailChimp level?

Comment: Sounds like the embed code from Mailchimp only adds subscribers to the list. From what you say that's working. What it doesn't do is automatically send emails to the subscribers on the list when a new post is published. You will need to add an additional mechanism to do that if you want it automated. Otherwise, you will just periodically create and and send emails to the subscribers on that list from Mailchimp. WordPress is simply a means for people to add themselves to the list. Everything else will be done in MailChimp or a WP-MC integration via plugin or custom code.

Comment: "What it doesn't do is automatically send emails to the subscribers on the list when a new post is published. You will need to add an additional mechanism to do that if you want it automated." Oh I thought it happens automatically once a person enters his/her email address and clicks subscribe button. So it doesn't send email automatically when a new post is created?

Comment: No. It only adds subscribers to the list. You need to create and send the emails to the subscribers on the list using another method, the simplest being directly from the Mailchimp account.

Comment: Do you mean every time I create a new blog post I have to login to my Mailchimp account and click something to send an email to subscribers about my new post? If this is the case I am not sure if MailChimp is the tool I need for the job. Is there any other free options to add subscribe to blog post by email other than Mailchimp?